# how the FruitChains consensus works in bitcoin

Tags: bitcoin-core, mining-theory, consensus

I came across the paper  [FruitChains: A Fair Blockchain](https://eprint.iacr.org/2016/916.pdf). The basic nakamoto blockchain algorithm seems to be slightly twisted with using fruits instead of directly inserting transaction in to the blocks.

Are the transaction first computationally solved in to fruits and then inserted in to blocks later?

How the fruit chain works in a simple language?